# Screen.width problem with content and conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css

Welcome I have simple problem with `screen.width` condition. 
It's my html code :

```
 <ul class="offer-image clearfix">
            <li>
                <figure class="figure-image bottom-left" >
                    <div id="fire">
                        <h3> lighting a fire!</h3>
                        -We Light a fire on evening<br>
                        -We are using only real wood<br>
                        -You will find the best pleaces for bonfire<br>
                    </div>
                    <img src="resources/img/fire-min.jpg" >
                </figure>
            </li>
```

I would like to change content in `fire`div so I've used javascript :

```
if (screen.width > 650) {
 document.getElementById("fire").innerHTML = "<h3> lighting a fire!</h3>";

} else if (screen.width < 650) {
    document.getElementById("fire").innerHTML = "<h3> lighting a fire!</h3>-We Light a fire on evening<br> -We are using only real wood<br>-You will find the best pleaces for bonfire<br>";
}
```

The main problem should be simple. When I am refreshing the page, the content is appearing from `document.getElementById("fire").innerHTML` and won't change content from else if condition when `screen.width` is higher than 650. Can somebody explain me why it doesn't work?

Comment: You have to use a resize-listener.

Comment: wrap your code in `window.onresize = function(event) {` might help

Comment: @MauriceNino that's actually not the case. The op mentions that they resize their window and then reload the page. Then nothing happens.

Comment: This looks like what you _actually_ want to do, is simply hide some text below a certain screen width. For that, you should no be using JavaScript in this instance here to begin with, but CSS media queries. Wrap the content after the h3 in an additional container element, and then either show or hide that using CSS, based on screen width.

Comment: weegee It work's :) thanks!

Comment: @weegee You are right I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [screen.width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width) returns the total width of the user's screen, in pixels so it will not change. In your case, it should be [window.innerWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) instead.

Comment: Thanks, when I added  window.onresize = function(){ //if else statement } the innerWidth started work!

Answer (score 2):

use `window.innerWidth` instead of `screen.width`, the first give you the current width, the later give you the original screen width..
moreover the `window.innerWidth` is static value so for you to keep having you content dynamic in case your screen width changes constantly use the onresize listener like this:

```js
        window.onresize = function(){
            if (window.innerWidth > 650) {
                document.getElementById("fire").innerHTML = "<h3> lighting a fire! grater than 650</h3>";

            } else if (window.innerWidth <= 650) {
                document.getElementById("fire").innerHTML = "<h3> lighting a fire! less than 650 </h3>-We Light a fire on evening<br> -We are using only real wood<br>-You will find the best pleaces for bonfire<br>";
            }
        }
```